# Is there any difference in the glass between Zeiss cine and photo lenses?

Tags: lens, zeiss

I've heard that the Zeiss cine lenses (Compact Primes, Ultra Primes, etc...) are just rehoused ZE/ZF.2 lenses. Are there any differences in the glass between their lenses of same focal length (i.e. Zeiss Planar T* 50mm f/1.4 vs CP.2 50mm T2.1 vs UP 50mm T1.9)?

Comment: Might be wrong so I won't post an answer, but I think usually cine lenses don't have aperture detents to allow smooth transitions in depth of field.

Comment: Even if the optical design is the same: They might be binned!

Answer (score 7):

The cine lenses are different optically in that they are designed to minimise focus breathing, that is small changes in focal length when focussing, however they are very closely related to still photography designs.

Answer (score 0):

Other then a few tweaks, cine lenses generally have more aperture diaphragms to obtain smooth round bokeh.

*Here are cine version's capabilities: (35mm cine lens)*

1. Fixed Focal Length
2. 35mm Full-frame coverage (24 x 36mm)
3. **14 High-precision Iris Blades**
4. Anti-reflex Coating
5. Internal Light Traps
6. Manual Focus / Manual Iris Focus Rotation
7. 300° Calibrated Lens Scales
8. Rugged Cine Style Housing

*Here are photo lens traits:(35mm photo lens)*

1. **9 blades**
2. Exceptional Color Control
3. T* Coating

As for the glass they are mostly the same except some cotings and light traps